# Saving string to text file in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a function for writing String to a text file. It works, but for some reason (encoding?) it adds some weird data to the beginning of the file.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    var file:File =  new File(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTF("Hello World!");
    stream.close();
```

When I open the file in Notepad++, it shows this:[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this `stream.writeUTFBytes("Hello World");` instead of `stream.writeUTF("Hello World!");`

if we use `writeUTF` then it write prefix the string with a 16-bit length word. if you use `writeUTFBytes` then it omit this prefix Length String.

Answer (score 3):

`writeUTF` prepends the length of the string before writing it to file. Use `writeUTFBytes` if you want to write only the string.